# What is the way to select a hard-coded value in a query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQL query that uses a hard-coded value:

```
select col1, col2, 'some hard coded value' as col2  
from table_a  
union all  
select col1, col2, col3  
from table_b
```

I tried the following in SQLAlchemy:

```
result = session.query(table_a.col1, table_a.col2, 'hardcoded value'.label('col3')
```

but got an `AttributeError`, which makes sense.  I also thought about adding the value in Python then doing the union.

How can I add this hard coded value to a SQLAlchemy query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`literal`](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal) construct.

```
from sqlalchemy import literal

result = session.query(
    table_a.c.col1, table_a.c.col2, literal('hardcoded value').label('col3')
)
```