# How do I express "WHERE 'value' like column" in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a where clause in *reverse order* with SQLAlchemy ORM. So instead of `Table.query.filter(Table.column.like(value))`, I'd like to end up with...

```
select * from table where 'mail.google.com' like domain;
```

...to select this row:

```
| domain       |
| ------------ |
| %.google.com |
```

Ideally, I'd be able to do this:

```
Table.query.filter(BinaryExpression('mail.google.com', Table.domain, custom_op('like')).all()
```

But it return the AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'self_group'.

How is this expressed in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the way to select a hard-coded value in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239647/what-is-the-way-to-select-a-hard-coded-value-in-a-query)

Comment: Similar, but my question is more specifically about creating a "like" where clause, instead of labeling a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal
Table.query.filter(literal('mail.google.com').like(Table.domain)
```