# Match subdomain to domain python sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am currently trying to match a subdomain to a domain stored in a mysqldb. I have solved the mysql query but i do not get how to do this in python sqlalchemy.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM domains
WHERE domain_name='dev.www.acme.com'
OR 'dev.www.acme.com' LIKE concat('%.', domain_name);
```

Class mapping is in place and i can easily map a domain to a stored domain in the DB.

```
ref = self.session.query(Domain).filter(Domain.domain_name.contains(dname)).all() 
for i in ref:
    print(i.domain_name)
```

Comment: Which part do you not get? Do you have a class mapped to the `domains` table, or are you using `Table` directly? Please include what you have already and describe how it's not working.

Comment: Yes, i have the entire class mapping etc. So i can map the domain to domain.    
```ref = self.session.query(Domain).filter(Domain.domain_name.contains(dname)).all()
        for i in ref:
            print(i.domain_name)```

Comment: This'll be a good reference for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783346/how-do-i-express-where-value-like-column-in-sqlalchemy. Producing the `CONCAT()` expression is as easy as `'%.' + Domain.domain_name`, if your model has a string type for that attribute.

Comment: Big thanx for the help :) That helped a lot.